# nfsiostat failing on 18.04

Tags: 18.04, nfs

I'm trying to use nfsiostat on Ubuntu 18.04 running in AWS with an EFS file system mounted.

Everything I try returns this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/sbin/nfsiostat", line 640, in 
    iostat_command(prog)
  File "/usr/sbin/nfsiostat", line 593, in iostat_command
    devices = list_nfs_mounts(origdevices, mountstats)
  File "/usr/sbin/nfsiostat", line 495, in list_nfs_mounts
    for device, descr in list(mountstats.items()):
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the `list_nfs_mounts` function was causing the problem.  The local variable `list` overwrites the built-in function of the same name.

I updated the function to what follows, and it appears to work now:

```
def list_nfs_mounts(givenlist, mountstats):
    """return a list of NFS mounts given a list to validate or
       return a full list if the given list is empty -
       may return an empty list if none found
    """
    xlist = []
    if len(givenlist) > 0:
        for device in givenlist:
            stats = DeviceData()
            stats.parse_stats(mountstats[device])
            if stats.is_nfs_mountpoint():
                xlist += [device]
    else:
        for device, descr in list(mountstats.items()):
            stats = DeviceData()
            stats.parse_stats(descr)
            if stats.is_nfs_mountpoint():
                xlist += [device]
    return xlist
```